# Angularjs Jquery IE 8 or higher not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.1 and jQuery 3.2.1 when I run my app on IE 8 or higher, got the following errors in console:

> SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is undefined file: jquery.dataTables.js,
>   ligne : 68, colonne : 3 SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is undefined file:
>   jquery.validate.js, ligne : 15, colonne : 3 SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is
>   undefined file: bootstrap-dataTables.js, ligne : 39, colonne : 3
>   SCRIPT5022: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery file:
>   bootstrap.min.js, ligne : 6, colonne : 31 SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is
>   undefined file: bootstrap-datepicker.js, ligne : 13, colonne : 9
>   SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is undefined file:
>   bootstrap-datepicker.it.min.js, ligne : 1, colonne : 2 SCRIPT5022:
>   Jasny Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery file: jasny-bootstrap.js,
>   ligne : 7, colonne : 38 SCRIPT5022: bootstrap-datetimepicker requires
>   jQuery to be loaded first file: bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js,
>   ligne : 1, colonne : 220 SCRIPT5009: « jQuery » is undefined file:
>   angular-datatables.js, ligne : 9, colonne : 2 SCRIPT1003: ':' expected

With a throw exception :

> $injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:

Any idea how to deal with this issue?

EDITED: THis is my app.js where a first error come in ligne  scope.$emit("fileSelected", { files }); with SCRIPT1003: ':' expected

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'restangular', 'ui.router',  'ngMessages', 'pascalprecht.translate','ui.bootstrap','angularSoap','ngTagsInput', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services' , 'myApp.filters','datatables' ]);


myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
$urlRouterProvider.when('index.html', '/index'); 

$stateProvider 
.state('index', {      url: '/index',       templateUrl: 'home.html' }) 
.state('popup', {     url : '/popup',      params: {       Model: null      }

}) 

myApp.config(function($locationProvider, RestangularProvider) {  
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(location.pathname); 
}); 

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state',function($rootScope, $location, $state) {

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState,
                    toParams, fromState, fromParams) {          
                    $rootScope.currentNavLink = $location.path();           

            });  
} ]);

myApp.run(function($rootScope, $modal,$state) {  
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState,toParams) {         
                if (toState.name == 'poup') {          
                        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                templateUrl : 'popup.html',
                                controller : 'PopupController',
                                backdrop: 'static',
                                keyboard: false,
                                size:'lg'           
                        });             
                        modalInstance.Model = toParams.Model;                   
                        event.preventDefault();         
                }       
                }else {             
                    return;         
                }   
            }); 
        }) 

myApp.directive('fileUpload', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {         
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = [];
                files = event.target.files;
                scope.$emit("fileSelected", { files });               
            });
        }
    }; 
});
```

Comment: (Why are you using jQuery? AngularJS has jQLite, they will contradict each other. Consider using ngBootstrap for the [datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples))

Comment: ok i delete the dependency of jquery and bootstrap and i remained only the dependency of angularjs, the errors are spreaded for all my controllers telling SCRIPT1003: ':' expected

Comment: that's a syntax error, check what line is it on and fix it. It would also help if you show your scripts as well as any dependancy injections

Comment: when i went to the line of the error i see that the synthax is correct. Can you suggest me how can i debug or analyse my app with IE? and how can i fix the compatibility IE and angularJS 1.5.1

Comment: Just because it points to that line of code, doesn't always mean it came from it. You should probably show your code: edit your question, or make a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/). Since you are constantly editing your code, I suggest to make another question with some of your code in it

Comment: i edited my question , the first error come in scope.$emit("fileSelected", { files }); with ':' expected

Comment: you have a huge chunk of code commented incorrectly. Check what needs to be commented around where `modalInstance` is used. You are opening your model in a comment, but some part of it is exposed, giving you an error with the wrong syntax.

Comment: If you are using `ui.bootstrap` (instead of `ngBootstrap`) consider switching `$modal` to [`$uibModal`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal). _Your question could have been resolved in minutes, if you only posted your code first_

Comment: Aleksey i don't that think it is a synthax error here because my app works on chrome and firefox. I tried also to change $modal to $uibModal and i got same errors

Comment: You have majority of your code commented incorrectly, it can't work

Comment: ah it's a malformed copy and past , i edited the code

Comment: your `if (toState.name == 'poup') {` is closed twice with `} }`. You `myApp.config(` is **not** closed with `});`. Once again, refactor your code, swap `$modal` with `$uibModal`, and try to ask a new question, this one is edited beyond the original scope of the question